# How to enable auto power on for a Google Coral Dev Board?

Tags: hardware, google-coral

Is there a way to automatically turn on the device whenever power is supplied?

What is currently happening is that when I connect the usb-c connector to the power it lits the ethernet orange light, but doesn't turn the device on. Then, if I remove the usb-c, it blinks the red power led, and when I reconnect the usb-c, device boots ok.

If the power is removed for more than what seems to be ~20 seconds, I would need to perform the entire process again (connect-disconnect-connect).

What if I want to have my device always on (eg.: after power outages device should be back online)? That seems to work just fine for raspberry pi's, for example.

Comment: Hi, You seems to be having issue with power supply. Please try with 5V/3A power supply.  Always on is possible with [Dev Board Mini](https://coral.ai/products/dev-board-mini) but not with [Dev Board](https://coral.ai/products/dev-board).

Comment: I'm using a Canakit power supply, outputs 5.1V 3.5A.
I think it's not a power issue since it's very consistent and seems a feature.
The main piece of information is that I can have the "Always on" on mini version but not on the std version. Can you confirm that?
Isn't the connect-disconnect-connect the correct procedure to power the device? Something funny is happening on my device then? Any pointers to docs? Thank you!

Comment: Please check page 13 for always on feature on dev board mini at: https://coral.ai/static/files/Coral-Dev-Board-Mini-datasheet.pdf

Answer (score 0):

It seems to be a power supply issue indeed.
As I previously mentioned I was using a **Canakit power supply 5.1V 3.5A** that presented that weird behavior.

**Solution**: Changing it to a **Anker PowerPort Speed PD 30** makes the device turn on as soon as we plug the usb-c.

**Additional info**: A co-worker could also reproduce it, although it doesn't happen with all of our corals and not limited to Canakit power supply.